# SSML phonemes work fine in Alexa service simulator but don't work on Echo hardware

Tags: node.js, alexa-skills-kit, ssml

I'm creating a simple Alexa skill and want to use SSML to pronounce some non-English words properly. While everything works fine in Amazon Service Simulator, I can't get it working on actual Amazon Echo hardware.

For example, I'm sending following response from Lambda service:

```
var cardTitle = "Test"
var speechOutput = "Test 1, red stick in French is <phoneme alphabet=\"ipa\" ph=\"bɑˈtɔn ˈɹuʒ\">baton rouge</phoneme>"
callback(session.attributes, buildSpeechletResponse(cardTitle, speechOutput, "", true));
```

Amazon Service Simulator shows received response as:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "outputSpeech": {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "text": "Test 1, red stick in French is <phoneme alphabet=\"ipa\" ph=\"bɑˈtɔn ˈɹuʒ\">baton rouge</phoneme>"
    },
    "reprompt": {
      "outputSpeech": {
        "type": "PlainText",
        "text": ""
      }
    },
    "shouldEndSession": true
  },
  "sessionAttributes": {}
}
```

If I click "**Listen**" in **Service Simulator**, the response is spelled out correctly, as **Test 1, red stick in French is baton rouge**.

However, when I test the same skill on actual Echo Dot hardware the response is:
**Test 1, red stick in French is phoneme alphabet equals ipa ph equals.......**

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to change:

```
 "type": "PlainText"
```

to be

```
  "type" "SSML"
```

Comment: That was it! Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. Please up vote the answer since it worked for you.

Comment: In that case, I amend my response to just "you're welcome" :-)